# Onbeforeunload event not working in Safari after clicking button "leave page"

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari

Need to catch leaving page event on: click link, click back button of browser and so on.

In Safari clicking "leave page" button kills onbeforeunload event, try
 https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onbeforeunload

Perhaps someone won this behavior or found an alternative solution?